# Deletion of .gradle Folder in User Directory Recreates Again a File under the name registry.bin.lock

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, wrapper

I am facing a problem with my Gradle Configuration. I want to completely delete my .gradle file but as soon as I do that, the folder gets recreated again only with a file under the name registry.bin.lock. There's no way for me to delete this file.

I want to install gradle wrapper again, but since this file existance I am getting the following error: "Error: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 50".

Any advices??? I am providing a picture of the file I am referring to...

[image: Problematic File]

Comment: as path implies - there must be a gradle daemon still running. you can kill the process from task manager - usually listed as java. Or restart the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your task manager if there's any Java process that runs and stop it. After that, you should be able to delete this file and stop also it's recreation.

Answer (score 0):

When you run gradle with `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, gradle daemon create `registry.bin.lock` on your `GRADLE_USER_HOME/.gradle/daemon/<gradle-version>`. Also, gradle daemon running on background.

Gradle daemon recreate `registry.bin.lock` when lock file deleted.

If you want to delete `.gradle` directory, there are two options.

1. kill gradle daemon before delete `.gradle`

```
$ jps
91432 Jps
6875
91146 GradleDaemon
$ kill -TERM 91146
```

2. gradle run without daemon

```
$ gradle <task> --nodaemon
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).